# jQuery: Calculate hours based on time in and time out

Tags: jquery

I have two textboxes (time in and time out). Time is entered in this format, hh:mm AM or PM, i want to calculate the hours between time in and time out. How can I do that?

Time In 
09:00 AM

Time Out
05:00 PM

Hours should be 8.

Comment: Using a date() object would be the way to do it, but you could also just compare the integers in the dates, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ7n5/)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var start= new Date("2013-1-1 " + end_time);
var end=new Date("2013-1-1 " + start_time);

var finaltime=(start-end) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
```

Comment: I think it has to be (end - start), to get the value in positive. Also, say the time in is 09:00 am and time out is 05:00 am. Correct hours should be 20 but it's showing -4.

Answer (score 0):

```
hours = parseInt(timeOut.substr(0,2)) + parseInt(timeOut.substr(3,2))/60;
hours += timeOut.substr(6,2)=="PM"?12:0;
hours -= parseInt(timeIn.substr(0,2)) - parseInt(timeIn.substr(3,2))/60;
hours -= timeIn.substr(6,2)=="PM"?12:0;
```

provided that you checked the data into the text boxes matches exactly the format that you specified in your question.

Also you get decimal values for fraction of hours (ex 8 hours 30 minutes ---> 8.5)